# How to know how many matches a mongodb query has

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my project I have a search bar where the user can search for other users.

I'm using MongoDB as my database engine, and mongoose on nodeJS for my server, and so far everything works, except for one thing, i would like to order the results by relevance.

Imagine i have this collection

```
{ 
    "nombre" : "Ramiro", 
    "apellido" : "Garcilazo", 
    "empresa" : "PEMEX", 
    "tamano" : "Grande(250+)", 
    "sector" : "Servicios", 
    "giro" : "Sustancias Químicas", 
    "actividad" : "Venta de petroquimicos", 
    "estado" : "Jalisco"
}
{ 
    "nombre" : "Luis", 
    "apellido" : "Alberto", 
    "empresa" : "GanaMex", 
    "tamano" : "Mediana (51-250)", 
    "sector" : "Construccion", 
    "giro" : "Agricultura, Ganaderia y Pesca", 
    "actividad" : "Graneros", 
    "estado" : "Aguascalientes"
}
{  
    "nombre" : "Ramon", 
    "apellido" : "Corona", 
    "empresa" : "CoronMex", 
    "tamano" : "Micro (1-10)", 
    "sector" : "Construccion", 
    "giro" : "Textiles, Prendas y Productos de Cuero", 
    "actividad" : "Venta de tiendas de campaña", 
    "estado" : "Ciudad de mexico"
}
{ 
    "nombre" : "Joe", 
    "apellido" : "Doe", 
    "empresa" : "Apple inc", 
    "tamano" : "Micro (1-10)", 
    "sector" : "Construccion", 
    "giro" : "Alimentos y Bebidas", 
    "actividad" : "Ejemplo", 
    "estado" : "Veracruz"
}
{ 
    "nombre" : "John", 
    "apellido" : "Smith", 
    "empresa" : "Google inc", 
    "tamano" : "Micro (1-10)", 
    "sector" : "Bienes", 
    "giro" : "Agricultura, Ganaderia y Pesca", 
    "actividad" : "XYZ", 
    "estado" : "Aguascalientes"
}
{ 
    "nombre" : "foo", 
    "apellido" : "bar", 
    "empresa" : "foobar inc.", 
    "tamano" : "Mediana (51-250)", 
    "sector" : "Servicios", 
    "giro" : "Alimentos y Bebidas", 
    "actividad" : "foo-bar", 
    "estado" : "Aguascalientes"
}
{ 
    "nombre" : "Jonathan", 
    "apellido" : "Ceja", 
    "empresa" : "It4Pymes", 
    "tamano" : "Grande(250+)", 
    "sector" : "Bienes", 
    "giro" : "Mineria, Petroleó y Gas", 
    "actividad" : "asdf", 
    "estado" : "Baja California"
}
```

And my current query looks like this

```
export function buscarProveedor(req, res) {
  var regTerms = [];
  //creates an RegExp array of all the terms the user searched
  var terms = req.body.term.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    regTerms.push(new RegExp(terms[i], 'i'));
  }
  //creates a single RegExp for all the term
  var regTerm = new RegExp(req.body.term, 'i');
  User.find({
      $and: [{
        //any of this that matches
        $or: [{
          nombre: regTerm
        }, {
          empresa: regTerm
        }, {
          sector: {
            $in: regTerms
          }
        }, {
          giro: {
            $in: regTerms
          }
        }, {
          estado: {
            $in: regTerms
          }
        }, {
          actividad: {
            $in: regTerms
          }
        }, {
          tags: {
            $in: regTerms
          }
        }]
      }, {
        //ignore this, just checks if is not another type of user
        empresa: {
          $exists: true
        }
      }, {
        //checks that doesn't gets the user that made the query
        _id: {
          $ne: req.body.id
        }
      }]
    }, '_id nombre empresa')
    .then(user => {
      //returns it to my front-end
      res.json(user).end();
    });
}
```

So, for example in my search bar I put "Construccion", the response would be

```
{ 
    "_id": 0
    "nombre" : "Luis", 
    "empresa" : "GanaMex"
}
{  
    "_id": 1
    "nombre" : "Ramon", 
    "empresa" : "CoronMex", 
}
{ 
    "_id": 2
    "nombre" : "Joe", 
    "empresa" : "Apple inc", 
}
```

But if I put "Construccion Textiles", I would get the same exact result, even though the id 1 got matched to 2 terms.

I would like to know how many matches it got so I can order it by relevance, putting at the top the one that got more matches.

Can I achieve that with the query, or i have to manipulate the data after,
I honestly have no idea, and i haven't seen this asked anywhere before.

Thanks.

---

**Edit**: Ok I used $match and $group to do this, but still havn't done what i want, I used this.

```
export function buscarProveedorAvansado(req, res) {
  var regTerms = [];
  var terms = req.body.term.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    regTerms.push(new RegExp(terms[i], 'i'));
  }
  var regTerm = new RegExp(req.body.term, 'i');

  User.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      $and: [{
        $or: [{
          nombre: regTerm
        }, {
          empresa: regTerm
        }, {
          sector: {$in: regTerms}
        }, {
          giro: {$in: regTerms}
        }, {
          estado: {$in: regTerms}
        }, {
          actividad: {$in: regTerms}
        }, {
          tags: {$in: regTerms}
        }]
      }, {
        empresa: {$exists: true}
      }, {
        _id: {
          $ne: req.body.id
        }
      }]
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      "_id" : "$_id",
      "nombre" : {$max: "$nombre"},
      "empresa": {$max: "$empresa"},
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }]).then(user => {
    console.log(user);
    res.json(user).end();
  });
}
```

And I get this result using the term "Construccion"

```
[{ 
    "_id": 0
    "nombre" : "Luis", 
    "empresa" : "GanaMex",
    "count": 1
}
{  
    "_id": 1
    "nombre" : "Ramon", 
    "empresa" : "CoronMex",
    "count": 1 
}
{ 
    "_id": 2
    "nombre" : "Joe", 
    "empresa" : "Apple inc", 
    "count": 1
}]
```

And Again i get the exact same result if I use the term "Construccion Textiles"

I've tried several things, using a $cond on the $sum:

```
 $sum:[{
     $cond: {
         if: {
             nombre: regTerm
         },
         then: 1,
         else: 0
     }
 }, {
     $cond: {
         if: {
             empresa: regTerm
         },
         then: 1,
         else: 0
     }
 }, {
     $cond: {
         if: {
             sector: {
                 $in: regTerms
             }
         },
         then: 1,
         else: 0
     }
 }, {
     $cond: {
         if: {
             giro: {
                 $in: regTerms
             }
         },
         then: 1,
         else: 0
     }
 }, {
     $cond: {
         if: {
             giro: {
                 $in: regTerms
             }
         },
         then: 1,
         else: 0
     }
 }, {
     $cond: {
         if: {
             estado: {
                 $in: regTerms
             }
         },
         then: 1,
         else: 0
     }
 }, {
     $cond: {
         if: {
             nombre: regTerm
         },
         then: 1,
         else: 0
     }
 }, {
     $cond: {
         if: {
             nombre: regTerm
         },
         then: 1,
         else: 0
     }
 }]
```

To get a mongo error.

I figured is problem of the $and's and $or's since technically at the end is a single true and i don't know if there's a workaround that.

Am I missing the obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the match function which performs a count across all the documents your query pulled back.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#perform-a-count

Comment: Ok, i tried to use the example on the link. [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/9DpuK4ZN) and it gave me this as a result

`[ { _id: null, count: 3 } ]`

How can I get every document separate and count every match, can you help me with that?